# Mongo search by short id that is not an ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, search

We have a collection of documents representing document upload jobs, like the following:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(807106),
    "_class" : "com.*.FileUploadJob",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2018-12-12T17:04:32.042Z"),
    "jobConfigurationId" : NumberLong(5382),
    "fileName" : "807106.xlsx",
    "rowCount" : NumberLong(2),
    "successfullyStagedRowsCount" : NumberLong(1),
    "status" : "COMMIT_COMPLETED",
    "rowProcessingComplete" : true
}
```

When I try to find this record, none of the following works:

```
db.fileUploadJob.find({"_id": ObjectId(807106)}) 
db.fileUploadJob.find({"_id": ObjectId("807106")}) 
db.fileUploadJob.find(ObjectId("807106")) 
db.fileUploadJob.find({"_id": "807106"}) 
db.fileUploadJob.find({"_id": 807106}) 
...
```

How do I find that elusive entry?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

```
db.fileUploadJob.find({"_id": NumberLong(807106)})
```

I had to copy and paste the document JSON to a text editor from Robo3T to see what type it was!